# Create Checkout Session with Stripe / Stripe.js not working

Tags: reactjs, node.js, stripe-payments, checkout

I integrated stripe on my personal project -- an art portfolio website with e-commerce capability in React.js on the front and Node.js, SQL on the back

trying to create successful stripe checkout sessions in my deployed web app, including code samples here, see what I tried section for more details.

BACKEND

```
app.post("/create-checkout-session", async (req, res) => {
  const requestBodyItems = req.body.items;

  let lineItems = [];

  for (const item of requestBodyItems) {
    const product = await stripe.products.create({
      name: "test product",
    });

    const price = await stripe.prices.create({
      product: product.id,
      unit_amount: Number(item.item_price * 100),
      currency: "usd",
    });

    lineItems.push({ price: price.id, quantity: item.quantity });
  }

  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    line_items: lineItems,
    mode: "payment",
    success_url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_URL}/success`,
    cancel_url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_URL}/cancel`,
  });
  // res.send(session.url);

  // return session;
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.send(session);
});
```

FRONT -- current code

```
const handleSubmitAtCheckout = () => {
    axios
      .post(
        `${API}/create-checkout-session`,
        {
          items: userShoppingCart,
        },
        {
          headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("RES FROM CHECKOUT POST", res);

        if (res?.request?.response) {
          setStripeUserCheckoutSession(res.data);

          // window.location.replace(`${res.data.url}`);
        }
      })
      .then((session) => {
        stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  };
```

FRONT -- previous code before implementation of code I saw in video above

```
 const handleSubmitAtCheckout = (e) => {
  //
  //   axios
  //     .post(
  //       `${API}/create-checkout-session`,
  //       {
  //         items: userShoppingCart,
  //       },
  //       {
  //         headers: {
  //           // "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  //
  //         },
  //
  //       }
  //     )
  //     .then((res) => {
  //       console.log("RES FROM CHECKOUT POST", res);

  //       console.log(res.request.response);
  //       if (res?.request?.response) {
  //         // setStripeUserCheckoutSession(res.data);

  //         window.location.replace(`${res.data.url}`);
  //       }
  //     })
  //     .catch((err) => {
  //       console.error(err);
  //     });
  // };
```

I was able to get successful checkout sessions working in localhost,

when I tested in the deploy version (hosted on: frontend: netlify.com, backendDB: render.com, tables/schema:elephantsql.com) I proceeded to my shoppingcart component where checkouts are made and hit the button that creates the checkout and the then it would hang.
After a very long the console would show a Cors access origin error. I tried setting this the access-control-allow-origin in the frontend POST request with a wildecard "*". I did the same thing in the POST route on the backend.

I consulted with someone at my bootcamp and the said the problem was probably that I was attempting to make a POST directly from the client side in the react app and that I should be using Stripe.js to process that request on the frontend instead.

I found a youtube video created by stripe Developers (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UjcSWxPNo18&list=PLy1nL-pvL2M4bDg02XQr_Y68h4um-vLk3) about 17 min in just in case anyone was interested.

I found my backend code was nearly identical and tried my best to imitate the frontend code trying to tailor it for my integration.

The result is that I stop having any result at all -- cors access origin error or otherwise.

Really need an assist, this is the last step for getting MVP on my personal project that I intend to use for the hiring process.

Thanks all!

Comment: Can you share the full CORS error here?

Comment: Sorry for delay: cart:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://portfolio-project-deploy-back.onrender.com/create-checkout-session' from origin 'https://main--jons-palace-of-art.netlify.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't adding CORS headers to an OPTIONS route allow browsers to access my API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/why-doesnt-adding-cors-headers-to-an-options-route-allow-browsers-to-access-my)